# Eliminate first and second number after a symbol in stata

Tags: stata

I have a variable `cn` that is a `string` variable that includes court case names.

For example, `1:2013-cv-10153` and `0:1979-cv-06704`.

I would like to remove the first two numbers after the `:` so that it appears as:

`1:13-cv-10153` and `0:79-cv-06704`

I've tried `substr`, but I keep getting an error.

Could someone please advise the best coding strategy in Stata?

Comment: "but keep getting an error"; which error ? also show the code you used to do the substring !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
display substr("1:2013-cv-10153", 1, 2) + substr("1:2013-cv-10153", 5, .)
```

Similarly:

```
. generate string = "1:2013-cv-10153"

. display string
1:2013-cv-10153

. generate new_string = substr(string, 1, 2) + substr(string, 5, .)

. display new_string
1:13-cv-10153
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also focus on the colon without worrying about its exact character position in the string.

You can do this using the `strpos()` function in addition to `substr()`:

```
generate string = "1:2013-cv-10153"

generate new_string = substr(string, 1, strpos(string, ":")) + ///
                      substr(string, strpos(string, ":") + 3, .)
```